# How to get two links on the same line but one on the left and one on the right?

Tags: html, text, href

```
<a href="example"><p style="text-align:left">Previous Page</a>  <a href="example"><p style="text-align:right">Next Page</a>
```

How do I get this on the same line?
I need it for school.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: thats not what he meant to type he's just genuinely bad @suraj

Comment: @L_Church the html snippet was already there.. it wasnt visible because it wasnt formatted as code. I didnt add anything extra

Comment: just looked like it then lol

Answer (score 1):

Use float right/left instead of text-align

```html
<a href="example"><p style="float:left">Previous Page</a>  <a href="example"><p style="float:right">Next Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css- float property.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .LeftLink{
            float : left
        }
        .RightLink{
            float : right
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<p class="LeftLink"><a>Previous Page </a></p>
<p class="RightLink"><a>Next Page</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```